# error 128 when trying to clone a git repository using jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, permission-denied, public-key

I can clone my git repository on the Linux server that hosts the Jenkins app, but when I'm trying to create a new Jenkins job to do so, I'm getting error 128.

"Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/proj.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Things I did

1. Install git on the Linux server.
2. Install BitBucket plugin and it's dependencies on the Jenkins app.
3. Create an SSH key.
4. Import the key to BitBucket and to Jenkins folder.
5. Set permissions to Jenkins user on the SSH key.
6. I created SSH credentials on Jenkins app.

**WORKS ON TERMINAL**

`bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$ whoami
jenkins
bash-4.2$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via a deploy key.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
user/proj: test3 -- jenkins@git`

.
.

`git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/proj.git
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-13 ~]$ git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/proj.git
db710fbf01f08789cf5c15e66269013f8e1543d4        refs/heads/master`

**IMAGES:**

[1-linux jenkins ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUVOY.png)

[2-ssh 2 git using default user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdRu7.png)

[3-ssh 2 git using jenkins user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u62BD.png)

[4-ssh rsa keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO5Bb.png)

[5-jenkins auth keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQFCH.png)

[6-jenkins cred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbXP2.png)

[7-jenkins web error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpNtH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to write the URL of the git repository, when configuring it in Jenkins, as `git@[...]` instead of `ssh://git@[...]`

On the other hand, the key you have introduced as private key of `test3` (`ssh-rsa AAA[...]`) doesn't seem to be a private key. It looks like the public key instead. The private key is a block that starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. In your case I think it's stored in the file named `jenkins_bitbucket_access` (the public key is stored in `jenkins_bitbucket_access.pub`)

Comment: it doesn't work at all without ssh, Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org/user/proj.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: 'git@bitbucket.org/user/proj.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Comment: i updated the authorized_keys file of jenkins as you suggested and also restarted jenkins service, and it still doesn't work.... still the same error

Comment: I didn’t suggested to change `authorized_keys` file, but the `test3` credentials configuration on Jenkins. By the way, when you are doing `ssh` from command line without specifying a specific private key, you are using `id_rsa` by default. Since that works, I would try on Jenkins without specifying any credentials, thus the default key pair should be used as well, shouldn’t it?

Comment: The URL format varies a little without the `ssh://` - it would need to be `git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git`, with a colon in place of the first slash.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I used my public key **instead** of the private key when I created the SSH credentials on Jenkins Web... now it all works :)